# How to get underlying object in Sonata's Admin class when called by sonata_type_admin?

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

So, in edit action of Sonata Admin I'm trying to display different form fields depending on *create* or *edit* context.

Maybe some background first..

I have a Gallery entity and a CoverPhoto entity bound with OneToOne.

**Gallery:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CoverImage", mappedBy="gallery", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 **/
private $cover;
```

**CoverImage:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Gallery", inversedBy="cover")
 **/
private $gallery;
```

Here's coresponding **GalleryAdmin** class:

```
class GalleriesAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
                -> add('name', null, array('label' => 'Nazwa'))
                -> add('category', 'sonata_type_model', array('label' => 'Kategoria'), array('subject' => $this -> getSubject()))
                -> add('cover', 'sonata_type_admin', array('label' => 'Okładka'))
                -> add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', array('by_reference' => false, 'label' => 'Powiązane zdjęcia'), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'inline' => 'table',
                ))
            ;
    }

    //other stuff 
}
```

And here we go with **CoverImageAdmin**:

```
class CoverImagesAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
                -> add('path', 'thumbnail', array('label' => 'Miniatura'))
                -> add('file', 'file', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Plik'))
        ;
    }
}
```

"Thumbnail" is my custom form field which displays thumbnail (shocker). But now i want this field only appear in "edit" context.

This should be piece of cake with

```
$this -> getSubject()
```

method of Admin class and condition. Unfortunately when I call getSubject() in CoverImagesAdmin class which is used to render nested form it always returns *null*. The same with getParent();

Calling getForm() results in

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached, aborting! in 
>   /home/flameheart/Projects/KolberPhotography/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component
>   /OptionsResolver/Options.php on line 350

I've tried to call about every method of Admin and FormMapper just to determine form's context but ended up with nothing.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this in a clean way ?

Comment: Just for the record, that maximum nesting level error is to do with XDebug and nothing to do with Sonata Admin

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to do it this way:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

    if($this -> getRoot() -> getSubject() -> getCover() && $this -> getRoot() -> getSubject() -> getCover() -> getId() )
    {
        $formMapper -> add('path', 'thumbnail', array('label' => 'Miniatura', 'attr' => array('id' => 'gallery_cover_image'), 'label_attr' => array('id' => 'gallery_cover_label')));
    }

    $formMapper -> add('file', 'file', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Plik'));
}
```

Imo, this Sonata thing really needs loads of documentation and refactoring instead of further development.

Comment: Flameheart you should mark this answer as valid if this solved your question. Greetings!

Comment: I agree about the refactoring.

Answer (score 7):

It's an old question, I know, but the cleanest way I have found of doing this is:

```
$this->id($this->getSubject())
```

If it returns true it is an edit form, if it is false, it is a create form.

Comment: Thanks for this. I added your solution to my blog: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/how-to-check-if-subject-is-new-resp-action-is-create-or-edit-in-sonata-admin/ - In addition you can check the same inside your template with {% if admin.id(object) is not null %}.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the subject inside of an admin with `$this->subjectExists()` and you can check the context of the `configureFormFields()` admin function with a function `$this->subjectExists()`. If it's true, you're editing, otherwise you're creating!